# After systemd upgrade, why does /dev/null always have the wrong permissions?

Tags: debian, systemd

After upgrading my Debian system, this happens:

```
# ls -l /dev/null 
crw-rw-r-- 1 root plugdev 1, 3 Feb 20 18:17 /dev/null
```

...which is bad. I can manually change the permissions, but it doesn't persist across reboots, of course. Most things work, but given that most (but not all) of the other device nodes are owned by plugdev, I think something's seriously wrong and it's only working by accident.

I suspect that what's happened is a borked upgrade to systemd. However, I barely understood udev, let alone systemd.

I can't find anything in the logs about initialising the device nodes. Nor can I find anything in the documentation. Nor can I find any udev rule files or systemd unit files which do this.

Has anyone seen this before, and if so, what might be going wrong? And if nobody has, where should I be looking to diagnose this?

Comment: I'd say `systemd` should be out of the picture there: the `/dev` hierarchy is populated by `udevd` and `systemd` merely starts it.

Comment: I've upgraded several systems from Wheezy to Jessie--no issues with `/dev/null` so far, and I have actually failed to google this problem. Try hitting the `#debian` IRC channel on `irc.oftc.net`.

Comment: I thought systemd emulated udev --- I certainly don't have it running.

Comment: ...so I *did* find the emulated udev --- `systemd-udevd.service` --- and it *is* running. A logfile said that one of my udev rules files was invalid. I've fixed that, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: That's not "emulated udev". That's actual udev. (And these days it doesn't create any device nodes anymore – the kernel's devtmpfs handles that, with some exceptions...) udev does however _change_ device modes/ownership, so if you end up with a system broken like this, I suggest starting with `grep -r plugdev /lib/udev /usr/lib/udev /etc/udev`.

Comment: Well, it's not the udev that's in the udev package, which is all that matters as far as I'm concerned...

Comment: ...and I tried changing the `/dev/null` group from plugdev to root. This time, when I rebooted, the change was sticky. What's more, a whole bunch of *other* device nodes that previously had the plugdev group now have the correct groups. (Such as `/dev/tty*`.) This is very mysterious.

Comment: Changing the group back to `plugdev` and rebooting didn't revert to the original behaviour --- everything is still fine (the group has been reset to null). So, shrug. I can't promise that changing the group fixed things, because I also started and stopped systemd-udevd several times, but it could have.

Comment: @kostix: you gave me the clue that led me to whatever it was that I did that fixed this. Thanks!